# Wordpress queries written in theme pages doesn’t return the result

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote the following code in front-page.php

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->ID;
echo $current_user->user_login;

global $wpdb;
`$wp_usersinfo = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * from wp_users WHERE name = %s",$current_user->user_login
    ),ARRAY_A
    );`
print_r($wp_usersinfo);
```

Which doesn't print any result of the queries but result of echo $current_user->ID and echo $current_user->user_login are printed. Where as same output was given when i tested in localhost.(currently i am coding to host in a domain)
But when i run code like:

```
print_r(count($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_users"')));
```

Output is generated.
Even when i try to make a function in functions.php and try to echo in front-page.php its doesn't work.
What am i doing wrong? Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd actually use this query, since essentially you're just duplicating your efforts when you already get the user data as an object when you use `wp_get_current_user()`.

But for the sake of your question, there is no field called `name` so your query shouldn't return any results.  It's also safer to use the `$wpdb->prefix` or the alias `$wpdb->users`.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->ID;
echo $current_user->user_login;

global $wpdb;
$wp_usersinfo = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * from $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s",$current_user->user_login ),ARRAY_A
    );
print_r($wp_usersinfo);
```

If you want the user object data as an array, you could just do this, and cast data as an array.

```
print_r( (array) $current_user->data );
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But the real problem is. I created a custom table “userrole” of these attribute:
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
role text NOT NULL,...
PRIMARY KEY (id)

And tried:

$userrole = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * from userrole WHERE name = %s",$current_user->user_login
    ),ARRAY_A
    );
print_r($userrole);

where name of the userrole matches with wp_users->user_login. And the result is not shown. Which was not problem when i was doing it in localhost. Could you help me? Thank You

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual data you're trying to query, and describe the table as well.